# Visibility raising exception?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create an application in C#.NET that has a connection to a simple SQL server database.

I have somewhere :

```
c2.CommandText = "delete from Courier where ID=" + Int32.Parse(txt_ID.Text);
```

The problem is that, when I turn the visibility of `txt_ID` to `false`, this error occurs :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.

but when visibility is true everything is ok ! Why ?

Comment: first of all use debug! see what is the value of text_ID.text.

Comment: Check to make sure the value of your Txt_Id.Text  is not being changed when you change visibility. Also try using lnt32.TryParse it will not throw an error just give you a Boolean result indicating success or failure.

Comment: @MarkHall i found that the txt_ID.Text is null when the visibility is false, but i don't know why!

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because txt_Id.text cannot be converted to an integer.

The Visibility of the control has no impact.

Comment: It's strange for me too! but when the textbox is visible, everything is ok and there is no error!
So what should I do to convert the txt_ID.text to an integer value?

Comment: Before your instruction with parse, show your Textbox and its content (for debug) : _txt_ID.Visible=true ; MessageBox.Show("Text=#'"+txt_ID.Text+"#");_ and chek that it contains no space.

Comment: I did what you said, and i found that the value of textBox is null when it's visible is false! but when the visible is true, the value of textbox is the specified ID.
I dont know whats the reason and why the visibility imacts the value of textbox!